# Modal to display data using AJAX in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

These few days I'm stuck with this modal thing.
I have a long list of data.. and in order to reduce too much data display on screen. I plan to use modal so when user wants to see details.. they just click on the particular data and system display all. However, in order to display all data, need to have another function to call. I look around and found that there's no way to call function to populate data and at the same time to open modal. So I try out AJAX & JS.

My problem .. the function didn't work to open modal and display data. APpreciate if you guys out there can help me.. Thanks in advance. Here's are my codes:

Modal: **modal-finance.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model_finance extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
}

// To list HMS data
public function get_hms_data() {

          $query = $this->db->select(array(
             'c.*',
             ), false)
             ->where(
                     'c.pan is NOT NULL',NULL,FALSE
                    ) 
             ->get('coll_tbl c');

         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
         }
         else {
           return false;
         }
}

// To list HMS data match with PBB data by PAN No
public function matched_by_pan($pan_no){
         $query = $this->db->select(array(
                 'c.*',
                 'p.approval_code',
                 'p.card_no'
             ), false)
             ->join('pbb_cc_tbl p', 'p.approval_code = c.approval_code','left')
             ->like(array(
                     'c.pan' => $pan_no
                    ))
             ->get('coll_tbl c');
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
             return $query->result();
         } else {
             return false;
         }  
}
```

Controller: **Finance.php**

```
class Finance extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_finance');
    }

    /* Function to call the view of finance */
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('pages/finance');
    }


    public function get_matchBYpan()
   {
        $this->load->model('model_finance');

          $cardData = $this->input->post('cardData');
          $last4pan = substr($cardData,12);
          echo $last4pan;


          if(isset($last4pan) and !empty($last4pan))
          {
                 $records = $this->model_finance->matched_by_pan($last4pan);
                 $i=1;
                 $output = '';
                 foreach($records as $row)
                 {
                        $output .= '      
                        <h4 class="text-center">'.$cardData.'</h4><br> 
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                               <th>No</th>
                               <th>Booking ID</th>
                               <th>PAN No</th>
                               <th>Approval Code</th>
                               <th>Method</th>
                               <th>Source</th>
                               <th>OTA</th>
                               <th>Amount</th>     
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <tr>
                               <td>'.$i.'</td> 
                               <td>'.$row->booking_id.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->pan.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->approval_code.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->method.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->source.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->ota.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->total.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>';
                 $i++;
                 }        
                 echo $output;

          }
   }
```

Views: **fin_match.php**

```
<!-- modal-tableHMS starts -->
     <div id="modal_tableHMS" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header no-padding">
                                                                                <div class="table-header">
                                                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                                                                                    <span class="white">&times;</span>
                                                                                                </button>
                                                                                                HMS data matched by last 4 digit PBB Card number (PAN)
                                                                                </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <div class="modal-body no-padding">
                                                                    <div id="hms_result"></div>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="modal-footer no-margin-top">
                                                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>
                                                                                Close
                                                                            </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                </div><!-- /.modal-table -->

                </div> <!-- /.main-content-inner -->
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view_data').click(function(){
        var cardData = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Finance/get_matchBYpan",
            method: "POST",
            data: {cardData:cardData},
            success: function(data){
                $('#hms_result').html(data);
                $('#modal_tableHMS').modal('show');
            }
     });
 });
```

});

```
<!-- other codes -->

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <center><h3 class="row header smaller lighter blue">
                <span class="col-xs-12"><b> PBB Data </b></span>
                </h3></center>
                <table id="dataTablePBB" class="table  table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Transaction Date</th>
                        <th>PBB Card Number</th>
                        <th>Card Type</th>
                        <th>Approval Code</th>
                        <th>Currency</th>
                        <th>Gross Amount</th>
                        <th>Trace No</th>     
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($PBBdata)):
                        $i=1;
                        foreach($PBBdata as $row)
                        {
                         echo '<tr>';
                         echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.$row->trans_date.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>';
                    ?>
                        <input type="button" name="view" value="<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>" id="<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm view_data"">

                    <?php
                         echo '</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.$row->card_type.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.$row->approval_code.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.$row->gross_cur.'</td>';                                   
                         echo '<td>'.$row->gross_amt.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.$row->trace_no.'</td>';
                         echo '</tr>';
                         $i++;
                         }
                         endif;
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> <!--col-xs-12-->
            </div>
```

Comment: do you get correct data on direct access to your controller->method? 

try this on browser address bar `/finance/get_matchBYpan/` and checkout if there is any error or not!

Comment: i adjust the code a bit.. can view now.. but can only display 1 data..  i'm trying to figure it out now.. i update my code above..

Comment: can you show me the output? and what do you want actually?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on your JS script has returning failure. If you are using Chrome you can check it on **Console** or **Network** -> *XHR* there are more detailed information regarding on that error.

And that $output variable must be array because the view needs a storage since it is inside *foreach* loop and return it like this *** echo json_encode($output)*** Please see more [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)